# REPL returns RDD values but SBT won't compile

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, apache-spark-mllib

When running the below method from a fresh spark shell REPL session everything works fine. However when I try to compile the class containing this method I get the following errors

```
Error:(21, 50) value values is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating)]
val training = ratings.filter(x => x._1 < 6).values.repartition(numPartitions).persist
                                             ^
Error:(22, 65) value values is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating)]
val validation = ratings.filter(x => x._1 >= 6 && x._1 < 8).values.repartition(numPartitions).persist
                                                            ^
Error:(23, 47) value values is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.recommendation.Rating)]
val test = ratings.filter(x => x._1 >= 8).values.persist
                                          ^
```

In both cases I'm using Spark 1.0.1 The code itself is as follows.

```
def createDataset(ratings: RDD[Tuple2[Long,Rating]]): List[RDD[Rating]] = {

    val training = ratings.filter(x => x._1 < 6).values.repartition(numPartitions).persist
    val validation = ratings.filter(x => x._1 >= 6 && x._1 < 8).values.repartition(numPartitions).persist
    val test = ratings.filter(x => x._1 >= 8).values.persist
    val numTraining = training.count
    val numValidation = validation.count
    val numTest = test.count

    println(" Number Of Training ::: " + numTraining + " numValidation ::: " + numValidation + " ::: " + numTest)
    List(training,validation,test)
  }
```

It is taken from the MLLib tutorial (Adapted slightly) , no idea whats going wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to have this line in your code

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
```

This imports the implicit conversions to [`PairRDDFunctions`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions) which is what allows you to call `values`. The spark REPL imports this for you which is why you don't see the error in the interpreter. Specifically this function in `SparkContext` does the conversion.

```
implicit def rddToPairRDDFunctions[K, V](rdd: RDD[(K, V)])
      (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K] = null) = {
    new PairRDDFunctions(rdd)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes perfect sense.